# Repository и Unit of work

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

прочитал я значит пару статей на metanite и совсем запутался, у меня такое ощущение что оба паттерна масло масляное так как один вроде как использует другой. Вот статьи которые прочёл

Репозиторий
https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php

unit of work
https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.3.php

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю зачем эти два паттерна нужны и какие преимущества, репозиторий вроде как даёт гибкость в плане использования б.д если я правильно понял, а я теперь в этом не очень уверен, а unit of work как мне показалось что вообще использует репозиторий когда можно и без него(unit of work) как мне кажется

Comment: Репозиторий инкапсулирует логику для работы с данными. К примеру `Users` хранятся у вас в Postgres (sql), для того чтобы не размазывать sql-запросы к БД по всей программе - вы делаете класс в котором описываете нужные вам sql-запросы. Всё. Паттерн Unit-Of-Work позволяет создать вашу логику атомарной (если брать сам контекст uow). Либо выполнилось и всё сохранилось - либо не выполнилось и не сохранилось.

Comment: [Полезная ссылка](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: @Kalmankantaja я вот посидел перечитал статьи, и заметил, что uow просто оборачивает два репозитория и работает с ними через два свойства и больше ничего. Теперь вопрос, каким образом он обеспечивает атомарность?

Comment: Обычно UOF регистрируют как Scope, т.е. на один запрос пользователя к АПИ будет существовать личный его UOF, в котором вы будете делать всё, что захотите, а потом одним разом всё сохраните (или не сохраните, если где-то будет ошибка/упала база/etc.). Так же еще не будет лишним сказать, что можно репозиторий создавать в самом UOF, а не явно указывать уже готовые (через свойства), будет что-то типа такого: ```unitOfWork.Repository<MyEntity>().Entities().Where(....).ToListAsync();```, а так же уже созданные репозитории кэшировать в uof.